# Soap 1.2 not working with stamps.com

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am feebly trying to implement a stamps.com api interface into my platform. This is my first time using SOAP, I event had to recompile PHP to enable the libraries.

I'm moving along but now I'm having a problem. They support soap 1.1 and soap 1.2 requests, and when I run the following code:

```
$client = new SOAPClient(
    './SWSIM.wsdl',
    array(
        'trace' => 1
    )
);
```

I get back a successful response from my request that comes after this.

However if I add the option to use soap 1.2 like this:

```
$client = new SOAPClient(
    './SWSIM.wsdl',
    array(
        'trace' => 1,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    )
);
```

I get the following error:

```
There was an exception running the extensions specified in the config file. ---> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: input
```

This line is not actually throwing the exception. Its the following command that throws it, but removing the soap_version is what "fixes it". I would like to use soap 1.2 so naturally this is bugging me.

FTR The command I'm running is this:

```
$authData = array(
    "Credentials" => array(
        "IntegrationID" => "MYUID",
        "Username"      => "MYUSERNAME",
        "Password"      => "MYPASSWORD"
    )
);

try { 
    $objectresult = $client->AuthenticateUser($authData);
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo "EXCEPTION: " . $e->getMessage();
    print_r($e);
    exit;
}
```

The WSDL file can be viewed here:
https://swsim.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv22.asmx?wsdl

I have also checked in with their developer support and they said:
"The message you are currently receiving is returned from whichever program you are designing your integration with. This has been commonly noted happening within Visual Basic where is creates a wrapper class that needs certain variables for the response. This could be similar to the behavior that you are experiencing. Please verify how your program language consumes a WSDL."

I also noticed that the __soapCall method excepts an "input headers" argument. I'm not entirely sure I should be / can even use that method in my code. I suppose I should just try and play with it.

Comment: Either there is a different input structure for Soap 1.2 (defined in WSDL) or the provider doesn't support Soap 1.2. As you haven't provided the WSDL link we can't help any further.

Comment: TY for your response. I have updated the question with the link to the WSDL. In addition to that, you can view com samples by accessing this url and clicking on an api function. It shows com samples for soap 1.1 and soap 1.2. https://swsim.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv22.asmx

Comment: I am doing the same thing trying to do the AuthenticateUser method, can you please tell me on what url you are sending the post request?

Comment: For production I'm using https://swsim.stamps.com/swsim/swsimv23.asmx?wsdl (version 23 corresponds to my integration level. this may be different for you) - For testing I'm using a local copy of the wdsl file.

Comment: Thats (https://) on that.

Comment: NOTE: The above wsdl is out of date. Contact stamps.com for the current wsdl!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your WSDL file. I was using the wrong one, and it appears you may be as well. Try this one: http://developer.stamps.com/developer/downloads/files/Stamps.com_SWSIM.wsdl

NOTE: The above is out of date. Contact stamps.com for the current wsdl!

Comment: I ended up just using the soap 1.0 calls so I cant verify this was the problem but screw it, I'll except this as the answer since you had this problem and were able to fix it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but here is an example class that should get anyone started with the stamps.com api in php https://github.com/aaronjsmith/stamps.com-php

Answer (score 0):

The WSDL looks fine and it's the same input structure for both Soap versions. The problem is a bug somewhere at their end, you'll have to contact them to resolve.

I would also test it via a .NET app just to see if it behaves the same.